# Richfaces fileUpload - this._q._curReq is null

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, websphere, websphere-8

I am using JSF 2 and Richfaces 4.2.3.Final on a Websphere AS 8 (I think it ships with MyFaces 2.0.2)

I get a javascript error when trying to upload a document with the rich:fileUpload

this._q._curReq is null

I found this solution

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10128

So I downloaded the latest MyFaces version, placed myfaces-api.jar and myfaces-impl.jar in my lib folder and configured the application classloader-order to "Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last) " and restarted my server.
It seems to have no effect at all, i still get the same error.

Is there more configuration needed on the WAS?

Someone has the same issue?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Edit: is there any way of finding out which Myfaces implementation is actually used for this application? In the server log I only find a warning that says MyFaces 2 is running in development mode, but it doesn't log the actual version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. There actually is another configuration I needed to do in Websphere.

Admin Console - Applications - Websphere Enterprise applications - appName - Manage Modules - moduleName - Class loader order:classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)

After that the latest myfaces version applies correctly and the fileUpload works.

Hope that helps people with the same problem.

Comment: Btw.: the first configuration was in: Admin Console - Applications - Websphere Enterprise applications - appName - Class loading and update detection